# Change values in specific rows

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a list of notifications:
[image]

The column that is called 'Close' is actually called Is_Read and is by default 0. I would like to achieve that when I click the X button the value changes to Is_Read=1 and will disappear from the list.

I already configured a dynamic action

[image]

And if true then it executes Server side code PL/SQL:

Update Notification_party set Is_Read=1 where  Notification_ID = :Notification_ID and Party_ID = :P_36_USER;

However nothing happens even when I refesh the page.
I think the problem is that when I press the X (which is a link) it does not know which row I am using.

Comment: did you mean submit instead of reloading the page manually? I'd add another dynamic action as SUBMIT PAGE after SET VALUE

Comment: You would need to follow path described in this post, to respond to an action of clicking on the icon. You could either delete the row and refresh the region, or delete the row and hide the row - but then pagination wouldn't match up
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html